# What is this step?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, proof-explanation

[image: Notes from analysis lecture]

Hello, I’m a first year engineering student and today our prof showed us this proof of the derivative of polynomials. However, I don’t understand how the second term is equal to the third term (the prof said we should know this from school so he did not explain). Could someone please explain to me about what happened there? I really can’t figure it out and don’t know how to search for it in the internet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write out the formula explicitly (replace the $\Sigma$ summation notation by the full sum it stands for) when $k=2$ and  $k=3$. Verify each by cross multiplying. Then you should see the general case.

Comment: Assuming you meant $\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ on the left also

Comment: [Please do not use images to convey information not otherwise present in your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks, I'll try that out

Comment: @pancini That's true! Thanks for the correction

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry, I don't have my laptop with me so formatting is difficult and I thought that's an easy enough question to be presented by an image. Will definitely type it out next time.

Comment: Easy enough to present, but it causes issues. Read the link to see why it is bad practice, and why your convenience translates into *in*convenience for others.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Did I mention the words "sorry" and "will definitely type it out next time"...? Explaining why I did that doesn't imply that I don't get why it's bad practice after your comment, sir.

Comment: No need to get defensive. SE is not a platform for flame wars. Whenever you think someone is being rude, stop and look for an interpretation that doesn’t require hypothesizing rudeness. Take a breath. Let it slide.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum I know. I read their comment at least five times to convince myself they weren’t being rude. Came to the conclusion that they thought I didn’t check the link, so I had to explain and be sarcastic bc it still felt rude to me. That was indeed a bit over it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact they are using is that, for $x\neq y$,
$$\frac{x^{n}-y^{n}}{x-y}=x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+x^{n-3}y^2+\cdots+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1}.$$

You can see this directly by multiplying both sides by $x-y$. On the right you get
\begin{array}
& x^n &+& x^{n-1}y &+& x^{n-2}y^2 &+& \cdots &+& x^2y^{n-2} &+& xy^{n-1}\\
&-& x^{n-1}y &-& x^{n-2}y^2 &-& \cdots &-& x^2y^{n-2} &-& xy^{n-1} &-& y^n
\end{array}

Comment: Ah! That makes sense! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AshaR Note that this is the sum of a geometric progression with common ratio $y/x$.

Comment: Note by the way that the case $n=2$ is a familiar identity; I think seeing this identity as a generalization of factoring the difference of two squares helps us remember it.

Comment: @AshaR Also I have to say this is a pretty specific thing to expect everyone to remember from high school or secondary school. Minor pet peeve of mine when instructors abuse that phrase.